# Applying OS Mastermap symbology in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, os-mastermap

I have downloaded OS MasterMap stylesheets from OS/Github.

How do I apply them in QGIS, all I get is style code rules for each symbology?
see below picture example from Topo area file.

[image: OS MasterMap Topo Area Rules]

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot looks like you're most of the way there, the Rule column is looking at the `style_code` field and saying every feature with the attribute of 1 will be displayed as a Building.

Of course, this assumes you have data in the correct format and has the relevant fields in the attribute table - which it should be if it has been provided by the OS, but is not clear from your screenshot.

Take a look at this doc from the OS for more info:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/user-guides/cartographic-stylesheet-user-guide.pdf

It goes through the steps required to apply the .QML files (stylesheets) from GitHub to your data, and will hopefully clarify if you're still having issues.

Comment: Hi I downloaded OSMM data for my area of interest in 2015, there is no style code column, I have tried looking at guides on github/OS but can’t work them out

Comment: It looks like the field was added not long after you downloaded the data to help improve displaying the symbology: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/forums/discussion/1009066/new-styling-options-now-available  I think your best bet is probably to contact OS and see if they can provide an update to your data, or a way to attach or generate the style information information:https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/contact/email-phone.html